# Display previous page results when we click back button in browsers

Tags: php, forms, post, http-headers

I have an application in PHP which is a search form.If i make a search in the search box and i submit the form then a list of products will get displayed then if i click any product it goes to the product page,now what is my issue is when i click the back option in the browser an alert for re-submission is getting still i go previous page search results are not shown
it is redirect to home page not to the search form also.

```
   Since i have list of variables i am using POST method instead of GET method.But if i use GET method there is no issue but i want to know whether the same can be in POST method also.
```

Comment: Good question. There are various work-arounds you could implement with cookies storing session information etc. (http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/session-cookies-used-for.html) but I always assumed that box you see saying "would you like to re-submit" would work exactly as you described. I'd be interested to know what the solution  here is.

Answer (score 3):

Use GET. There's a lot of debate about what qualifies for each of the HTTP verbs, but generally speaking this fits squarely in the GET world. The POST warning by the browser is unwarranted: the first sign that you shouldn't be using it for this particular operation (search).

Comment: If you switch to using GET, the form fields will be parameters in the URL, which means the user will be able to bookmark the search result. As Stefan pointed out, just because it's a form, doesn't mean it should be a POST.

Comment: Still doesn't entirely explain his problems with the POST form. Should still work, no?